# adding a column of a database to get the sum then divide to get a percent

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have info in a database structured like this :

```
shoe size name    weight
9         bob     150
9         tom     250
9         joe     100
5         billy   75
5         franky  80
etc.
```

you get the idea. I want to add up the weight by shoe size then divide each one to get a percent. So shoe size 9 will be 500. Then by the sum divide each size .. so bob would be 30% of the shoe size group 9, tom would be 50% of the shoe size group 9 and joe would be 20% of the shoe size group 9

any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(weight) as sum, COUNT(*) as count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY size
```

This will give you the sum of the weights and the number of each size, you can then get the average

Or if you want to do it in one shot

```
  SELECT  size, SUM(weight)/COUNT(*) as average
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY size
```

EDIT  - I Misread your question, here is a query that will do what you asked

```
   SELECT  b.name,  b.weight/sum(a.weight) as average  
   FROM  table as a JOIN table as b on a.size=b.size     
   WHERE  1 group by a.size, b.name
```

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but how would i then echo the generated % for each person?

Comment: Each record Has the average , name of the person and size

Comment: can you give me an example?